# Refund bounties if they cannot be awarded

Tags: feature-request

**Current Case:**
Offer a bounty on a question. Question is a decent question (positively upvoted). 1 week later, question has had no answers, bounty expires and disappears.

**Suggestion:**
In the case where it's a reasonable question which, regardless, garners no response. The bounty is refunded upon expiration.

Thoughts?

Comment: Take out an ad in a newspaper to sell something and nobody buys it would you expect the newspaper to give you the money for the ad back?

Answer (score 9):

You paid the reputation to get the attention for the question. You got attention on the question. Even tho there wasn't an answer, you already paid and got the attention, which is non-refundable.

Bounties are always paid upfront and not refunded. That's just how they work.

You should read about [bounties in the help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).